# Google Swiffy converted animation blocks touch events

Tags: javascript, html, google-swiffy

I am currently making a website that has html5 animation from a swiffy conversion in it. Everything is fine except when  on a touch device, where it seems to block any touch events occuring within it's borders. So when the user zooms in on an animation they have no way of zooming back out again because their pinch gesture isn't recognised.
Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the swiffy output ( which renders as a "div" ) some height and width via CSS. Did the trick for me :

```
div {
height:100%;
width:10%;
}
```

In my case the swiffy output wasnt affected in size at all, however i was able to scroll and swipe again.